# Git clone fatal error inside Virtual Machine

Tags: git, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to clone a repository inside a virtual machine running Ubuntu server 18.04.05 but every time I try I get an error. This is the repository I'm trying to clone https://github.com/webpwnized/mutillidae. I'm using VirtualBox 6.1.14, with 20gb hard drive and 5139mb ram. When I try to clone I get:

error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)/s

fatal: pack has bad object at offset 149322: inflate return -3

fatal: index-pack failed.

or

fatal: pack has bad object at offset 149322: inflate return -5

fatal: index-pack failed.

Comment: At which stage during the clone does this message appear? Sounds like a corrupt repo. Does it happen consistently? You could clone it on your host, copy it to the VM and try some git operations to see if the corrupt behavior persists.

Comment: The problem appears when the repo is downloading and it happens consistently, I tried to clone the repo outside the VM and it worked perfectly.